# Padding Spaces in a NSString

Tags: objective-c, string, nsstring

The following question is for Objective C preferably (Swift is fine too). How can I get my strings to look like the strings in the picture below? The denominators and the right bracket of the percentage portions need to line up. Obviously the percentages could be 100%, 0%, 0%, which means that the left bracket for the percentages wouldn't line up, which is fine. The amount of space that the percentage part requires would be 9 spots.

[image]

Comment: Strings are made visible to users with UILabels.  You could achieve this by arranging 6 labels in code or in IB

Comment: Sure, but how can I do it with one string for each line?

Comment: What if you set the UILabel to be right aligned?

Comment: Let's say the first value is 50/50 and (100%), then the rest won't line up.

Comment: Just use two labels per line.

Comment: Yeah, that's pretty much what I've gone with now :(

Answer (score 0):

I would strongly encourage using the layout engine for such things, but you could simulate yourself with something like the following, which I haven't tested...

```
// given a prefix, like @"5/50" and a suffix like @"(80%)", return a string where they are combined
// add leading spaces so that the prefix is right-justified to a particular pixel position
//
- (NSString *)paddedPrefix:(NSString *)prefix andSuffix:(NSString *)suffix forLabel:(UILabel *)label {
    // or get maxWidth some other way, depends on your app
    CGFloat maxWidth =  [self widthOfString:@"88888/50" presentedIn:label];
    NSMutableString *mutablePrefix = [prefix mutableCopy];
    CGFloat width = [self widthOfString:mutablePrefix presentedIn:label];
    while (width<maxWidth) {
        [mutablePrefix insertString:@" " atIndex:0];
    }

    // the number of blanks between the prefix and suffix is also up to you here:
    return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@     %@", mutablePrefix, suffix];
}


// answer the width of the passed string assuming an infinitely wide label (no wrapping)
//
- (CGFloat)widthOfString:(NSString *)string presentedIn:(UILabel *)label {
    NSAttributedString *as = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:string attributes:@{NSFontAttributeName:label.font}];
    CGRect rect = [as boundingRectWithSize:(CGSize){CGFLOAT_MAX, CGFLOAT_MAX}
                                               options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin
                                               context:nil];
    return rect.size.width;
}
```